# Mail controller sheet and partial page curls

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm using a `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` modal transition in my storyboard, showing a `ViewController` when clicking on a button. I have a button inside `ViewController` that I'm using it to display `MFMailComposeViewController` to send mail. The problem, is partial page curl is still visible and is obstructing the `MFMailComposeViewController` e-mail page on the top.

How do I show the `MFMailComposeViewController` on top of the partial page curl effect or hide the partial page curl effect while the `MFMailComposeViewController` is displayed and once the `MFMailComposeViewController` is dimmissed by pressing Cancel or Send, I want the partial page curl to be shown again.

for some reason on the `iPad` version, this the page curl disappears fine, yet occur on the iPhone version...

thanks in advance

Thanks.

Comment: in other words, my mail sheet appears below my partial curl. so there is no way to send or cancel the emails.

Comment: unfortunately i do not have enough rep points to post the image, but u guys get the jist of it from my description above